# Resize Image - SDWebImage -

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am displaying image using **SDWebImage**. You can check below code.

```
cell.imgPackage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "MY URL STRING")! as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "testPlaceholder.png"), options: .refreshCached)
```

**I need to resize width and height of server image and set in tableview cell image.**

My server image resolution is around
width - 1519
height - 950

and tableview having - 
width - 320
height - 150

let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code to scale your image.

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        img.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2016/06/macos_sierra_big-sierra-100667928-orig.png"), placeholderImage: nil) { (image: UIImage?, error: Error?, cacheType:SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: URL?) in

        //new size
        self.img.image = self.resizeImage(image: image!, newWidth: 600)

        //original size
        //self.img.image = image
    }

}

func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little too late, but for others, if you already know the dimensions you want, you can use the

> SDImageResizingTransformer

```
let transformer = SDImageResizingTransformer(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300), scaleMode: .aspectFill)
yourImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "url_to_your_image"),  placeholderImage: nil, context: [.imageTransformer: transformer])
```